# Difference of two Dates shows 6 days too much

Tags: javascript, date

```js
const oldDate= new Date('2019-07-19T19:20:00'); 
const newDate = new Date('2020-07-19T19:20:00'); // 1 year later

let timeDiff = new Date(newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime()); 
    
const years = timeDiff.getFullYear()-1970;
const months = timeDiff.getUTCMonth();
const days = timeDiff.getUTCDay();  // why 6 days ????

console.log(days);
```

I try to calc the difference between two dates and show it as years, months, days.

I really don't know if there is something wrong in the code or why are there 6 days as a difference? Should it be not 0?

```
const oldDate= new Date('2019-07-19T19:20:00'); 
const newDate = new Date('2020-07-19T19:20:00'); // 1 year later

let timeDiff = new Date(newDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime()); 
    
const years = timeDiff.getFullYear()-1970;
const months = timeDiff.getUTCMonth();
const days = timeDiff.getUTCDay();  // why 6 days ????
```

Comment: 6 is the day of the week [check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay)

Comment: `getUTCDay` returns the UTC day of the week numbered 0-6. when you convert the time difference to a date as you have, that date is 1/2/1971 in UTC, which is a saturday. I don't understand the logic in converting a time DIFFERENCE to a date in the first place. a day of a month can't have a 0 value no matter what.

Comment: This is not a valid way to get the difference between two dates, there are [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+difference+between+dates) already on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **Date.prototype.getUTCDate()**
> Returns the day (date) of the month (1–31) in the specified date according to universal time.
>
> **Date.prototype.getUTCDay()**
> Returns the day of the week (0–6) in the specified date according to universal time.

So you likely wanted `.getUTCDate()`, not `.getUTCDay()`.

Comment: still getting 2 days too much :/

Comment: Time deltas cannot be represented as `Date` objects. The results of subtracting two `Date` objects is a number representing their difference in seconds. Trying to supply that in constructing a `Date` object is likely to be interpreted as a Unix timestamp which are non-linear.

Comment: @Ouroborus—you mean difference in milliseconds.

Comment: @RobG Err, yes, milliseconds